# Crontab not functioning properly

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron

I am trying to run a crontab on Ubuntu, I think I get the general idea of how to create a crontab

I did the following...

1) run command `crontab -e`

2) add entry `04 22 * * * /var/www/update_ranks >> /root/update_ranks.root.txt`

3) check a text file was created under root/ named `update_ranks.root.txt` at the specified
   time.

The file `update_ranks.root.txt` is empty and the php file is not executed, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `update_ranks` is a bash file try adding sh before the script `sh /var/www/update_ranks`

By the way, check if you are doing that as root user or user with writing rights to `/root`. Try `sudo crontab -e`.

**EDIT:**

If it's a PHP file, you need to execute it in php `/usr/bin/php /var/www/update_ranks` and if the file has extension, use this: `/usr/bin/php /var/www/update_ranks.php`

Comment: Thanks `20 22 * * * /usr/bin/php  /var/www/update_ranks.php >> /root/update_ranks.root.txt` seemed to work great, im guessing you have to call the php executer for files like this?

Comment: Glad to help you. And yes, you have.